# How do you use Reactive Forms in an Angular Elements custom element?

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I'm trying to create an Angular Elements component to embed in a hosted web page, and I want my component to contain an Angular reactive form.

Build fails with error: "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'."

Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: This is Angular 9 and TypeScript 3.7 running on the latest version of the Angular CLI. Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-57wq1s

Edit 2: The updated Stackblitz code no longer throws a compile-time error, but the control does not finish rendering. The Submit button does not render. If I remove the 'formControlName' directive from the password input, the component *does* render completely.

Edit 3: StackBlitz seems to be working now, but if I download to my computer, npm install and ng serve, I get the problem where it renders the textbox but not the button.

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <app-password-reset></app-password-reset>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [PasswordResetComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    const passwordResetElement = createCustomElement(PasswordResetComponent, {injector});
    customElements.define('app-password-reset', passwordResetElement);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap(): void { }
}
```

**password-reset.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="resetForm" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit($event)">
      <input type="password" formControlName="password">
      <button type="submit">Reset Password</button>
    </form>`
})
export class PasswordResetComponent {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  resetForm = this.fb.group({
    password: [null, Validators.required],
  });

  formSubmit(event: Event) {
    alert('it works');
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you also need to import FormsModule

Comment: OK, I added that to my app.module.ts, and I'm still getting the same error. I'll update my original code sample.

Comment: can you create this project in https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: I got it into Stackblitz, but I'm not sure if it's compatible with Angular Elements. It's giving me a different error...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsyral

Comment: @SatishPai -- forgot to tag you

Comment: @Chad now the current error we are getting is different from what was mentioned in the question. Do you want to create the component dynamically ?

Comment: @SatishPai -- OK, my mistake. I've updated a package and fixed the secondary problem. If you go back to the StackBlitz, you should now see that it only partially loads the control. The sumbit button is missing. This is not the original error, but it's a symptom of the same problem.

Comment: @Chad i am getting this error `TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function` from your shared stackblitz. Have you saved the changes after the changes in package file ?

Comment: @SatishPai -- The fix for that was to pin the version of document-register-element to version 1.8.1. I've just saved it. Should be working now.

It appears that the whole component is now working for me in StackBlitz, but if I download to my local computer, run npm install and ng serve, I'm getting the problem where the text box renders but the button doesn't.

Comment: @Chad checking now there is no error.

Comment: @Chad what version of chrome you are using ?

Comment: @SatishPai -- 79.0.3945.130

Comment: @SatishPai -- Very strange. I'm getting weird variations on this problem depending on the project and environment. In my real application where I'm trying to solve the problem, the custom element doesn't render at all, like you are seeing. Sometimes when I run the example in StackBlitz it works, especially when I fork the project into a new one. Sometimes it doesn't. When I download the project from StackBlitz and run locally, I can see the textbox inside the component render, but not the sumbit button. Other times I get the error in my original post.

Comment: @Chad agree i am able to reproduce the same issue now. TextBox is render but not the button, need to check it

Comment: @SatishPai -- Looks like this could be an issue with Ivy. Here's a StackBlitz using the Angular CLI v. 9 with Ivy: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-57wq1s and here's one on CLI 8 without Ivy: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqvkzw

Non-Ivy works for me while Ivy doesn't. Are you seeing the same?

Comment: @Chad I agree with you. I am trying a way were ivy will work with custom element

Answer (score 1):

First Import `FormsModule` in your `app.module.ts`

You can use `FormBuilder` to build your form and set the password using `Validators`. It's easy to use and facilitate working.

Here's how I do it.

**Html Page**

```
<form [formGroup]='addEventForm' (ngSubmit)='addEvent(addEventForm.value)'>
</form>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

addEventForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
this.addEventForm = formBuilder.group({
  title: [null, Validators.required],
  location: [null, Validators.required],
  description: [null, Validators.required],
  startDateValue: [null, Validators.required],
  endDateValue: [null, Validators.required],
  startTime: [null, Validators.required],
  endTime: [null, Validators.required],
  eventType: ['payed'],
  price: ''
});
}
```

Please note that you need to import `FormBuilder`.

Hope that helps you a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I refactored my code to import the FormsModule and use FormBuilder, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: can you please update you're question with the new code

Comment: Instead of `password: [null]` please make it `password: [null, Validators.required]` and import `Validators` from `@angular/forms` also.

Comment: OK, now it builds without complaining, but it doesn't render the component. Now if I inspect the HTML while the app is running, there's just <!--container--> where the component is supposed to be.

Comment: Okay so the password text box is loading, and there's no error in the console log. What are you expecting? The Alert?

Comment: A button should be loading, and when clicked, it should alert.